# How www.hashbang.com opens localhost

Tags: localhost, hashbang

When i type **hashbang.com** it open **localhost/xampp** is it installed as virtual domain in computer or it's real domain ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They pointing to the local 127.0.0.1

Dont know why, but they do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thing hashbang is something that used by local server because when we `ping` that domain then it directly response through 127.0.0.1 so i think that is used by local server and when local server was closed it does not appear.

[image]

Comment: Because it's wrong. It's not some domain that is used by your local server. The A record for hashbang.com simply points to 127.0.0.1